# Can I downscale/upscale my MySQL server automatically?

Tags: mysql, upgrade, azure-vm, downgrade

Is this doable? Since we know the peak times of our platform we are planning to downscale our DB after peak hours then upgrade the specs before the start of peak hours, how can we do this? Like how is RDS doing this?

Comment: What's the read/write and can your application handle read/write split? Which MySQL version?

Comment: How many hours long is the spike?  Is it at a predictable time?  Is it mostly readonly traffic?

Comment: @danblack mostly read/write transactions. no, application can not handle read/write split. MySQL 5.7 sir

Comment: @RickJames around 4-5 hours from 9am until 2pm only on weekdays. Very minimal traffic after that timeline.

Answer (score 0):

the feature you want is currently in preview - it is called flexible server for mysql

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/mysql/flexible-server/

Comment: Still, their PaaS offerings is very costly for a startup company. We are planning to do this on their Azure VM.